# Active router link Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routerlink, routerlinkactive

How could i implement active router link if i have dymanic list of routes and cant assign a fixed route ?
[image]

I tried to implement a function which on click send index and search in DOM its array position in sidebar.
It works, but when we delete or add one more section, on update, it lost. Maybe someone have another ideas. Actual code:
[image]

Comment: What is your problem? You don't need to add the "active" class by hand. This does `routerLinkActive` itself. And dynamically creating is not a problem.

Comment: @Flo, it does not, as I saw, without passing routerlink :/

Comment: Ah I see you don't set routerLink in the html element. Then it will not working, that's right. use `ngClass` instead .classList.add() and it will work, too

Comment: @Flo, ngClass would not add class for all the a tags in *ngfor?

Comment: Or you mean to pass it in typescript ?

Comment: Yes, use `ngClass` or you can add the `routerLink` and bind it in each element. Then the `routerLinkActive` will do its job.

Comment: @Flo, thank you so much !!!
[routerLink]="['/document', section.id, section.recordType]" in HTML, works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use `routerLink` to using the `routerLinkActive` functionality. A way here is to bind the data like this:

**Code**

```
const sections = [{name: "Home", link: ["/home", "other"]},{name: "Contact", link: ["/contact"]}]
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let link of sections" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="link.link">link.name</li>
</ul>
```

This is a easy way. And if you don't wanna use `routerLink` you need to do it by yourself. One way is to use `ngClass`.
You check if the `activatedRoute` url is **home** as example. Then you set a variable to "home" and check it with `ngClass` like this:

**Code**

```
activeRoute: string = "";

constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    if (activatedRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url.indexOf("home") > -1) {
      this.activeRoute = "home";
    } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let link of sections" [ngClass]="{ active: activeRoute === 'home'}">link.name</li>
</ul>
```